# Django Calculated Running Balance

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Personal Finance App using Django (Creating an API Based Backend). I have a transactions table where I need to maintain the running balance based on the UserID, AccountID, TransactionDate. After Creating, Updating, or Deleting a Transaction I need to update the running balance. The current method I have identified to do this is by running a custom SQL statement which I call once one of the above operations has been done to update this field (see code below):

```
def update_transactions_running_balance(**kwargs):
    from django.db import connection


    querystring = '''UPDATE transactions_transactions 
    SET 
        transaction_running_balance = running_balance_calc.calc_running_balance 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
            transaction_id, 
            transaction_user, 
            transaction_account, 
            SUM(transaction_amount_account_currency) OVER (ORDER BY transaction_user, transaction_account, transaction_date ASC, transaction_id ASC) as calc_running_balance 
        FROM 
            transactions_transactions 
        WHERE 
            transaction_user = {} 
            AND 
            transaction_account = {}) as running_balance_calc 
    WHERE 
        transactions_transactions.transaction_id = running_balance_calc.transaction_id  
        AND 
        transactions_transactions.transaction_user = running_balance_calc.transaction_user 
        AND 
        transactions_transactions.transaction_account = running_balance_calc.transaction_account'''.format(int(kwargs['transaction_user']), int(kwargs['transaction_account']))

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(querystring)
```

However the issue I have is once the table gets a little larger, the response time started to increase (The SELECT statement is where the time is taken). The other issue I have is when I load the server with multiple concurrent create transactions, every once in a while (current rate is 0.25%) the running balance update fails due to the following error:

- ERROR:  deadlock detected.
- Process 7038 waits for ShareLock on transaction 5549; blocked by process 7036.
- Process 7036 waits for ShareLock on transaction 5551; blocked by process 7038.

I was wondering if there was a better way to do this? I originally wanted to define the running balance field as calculated field in the Django Model but I couldn't figure out how to define the it so that it achieves the same result as the code above. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.